# 13.04 -> 13.10 = black screen after GRUB, before login

Tags: kernel, 13.10

I'm fairly new to Linux so fancy lingo will need explaining :-)

Updating Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10 has resulted in a black screen after selecting Ubuntu in GRUB. I can still select any other operating systems in GRUB without issue including Ubuntu's Recovery Mode.

My current GRUB2 options are:

```
Ubuntu (<-- this is the one that black screens, 13.10)
Ubuntu Recovery Mode
Memtest
Mint
Mint Recovery Mode
Ubuntu (different, old install, 13.04)
" Recovery Mode
Windows 8 (here at the moment)
```

A bit of searching suggested that it's a kernel issue with UEFI; my motherboard has no compatibility options so that's a no-go. There's also no "Previous Linux Versions" option/submenu under GRUB.

Is there any way of updating the kernel from the recovery menu? Or rolling it back? Or is it a completely separate issue?

Help appreciated.

Comment: You can try dropping to a root shell in the recovery menu then executing `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` which will upgrade the terminal, but it may or may not help.

Comment: There's no network access in recovery though is there?

Comment: Choose the `netroot` option to use a root shell with networking.

Comment: This is what I see: https://lh3.ggpht.com/-arrPwliiteM/UEySmgF2hTI/AAAAAAAAGW4/jzOdSRfeTCQ/s640/recovery-mode-ubuntu-3.png So do I type netroot into the terminal or use the networking option? Because selecting the networking option throws me a mounting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. Turns out it was an issue of my own creation with /etc/fstab. These are the steps I took to fix it:

1) Boot into Ubuntu's recovery mode and select the option that provides access to the root shell/terminal/command-line.

2) Enter the following to provide write access to the drive (incl/ crucially fstab):

```
#mount -n -o remount,rw /
```

3) Next you'll want to open fstab in nano (think of nano as the shell equivalent of gedit):

```
#nano /etc/fstab
```

4) Remove whatever you added there to cause the problem or comment it out with a hash (#). Hit Ctrl+X, then Y, then ENTER, or whatever other combination of keys (there's a guide at the bottom) allows you to save and write the changes and exit.

5) Enter the following to cleanly reboot. It may take a moment.

```
#shutdown -r now
```

If your problem is anything like mine that's it fixed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this software it can help solve boot issues or grub related problems

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Won't help, the problem seemingly is the kernel or some other updated part of Ubuntu 13.10.